# How can I parse this configuration file format (allowing comments) in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am reading some parameters (from user input) from a `.txt` file  and want to make sure that my script could read it even a space or tab is left before that particular parameter by user.

Also if I want to add a comment for each parameter followed by # , after the parameter (e.g `7870 # this is default port number`) to let the user know about the parameter

How can I achieve it in same file?

Right now, I am using `split /\|\s/`.

#### Code:

```
$data_file="config.txt";
open(RAK, $data_file)|| die("Could not open file!");
@raw_data=<RAK>; 

@Ftp_Server =split(/\|\s/,$raw_data[32]);
```

#### config.txt (user input file)

```
PING_TTL   |   1
CLIENT_PORT |   7870
FTP_SERVER  |   192.162.522.222
```

Could any body suggest me a robust way to do it?

/rocky

Comment: The only robust way would be to mercy kill the code. By the way, you might want to spend a little teeny bit of time trying to learn how to use the site.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are doing this as a learning exercise, the best approach is to use a config parsing module from CPAN. Here's an illustration using [Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config::General), which is flexible enough to accommodate your unusual delimiter, and it provides a nice OO-style access to config parameters. [Note: To use this example, you'll need to install the `Config::General` module first. I mention this because it looks like you had trouble running Sinan's example, which also requires that you install a module from CPAN.]

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::General;

my $c = Config::General->new(
    -ConfigFile     => $ARGV[0],
    -SplitPolicy    => 'custom',     # Define | as our delimiter.
    -SplitDelimiter => qr/\s*\|\s*/,
    -ExtendedAccess => 1,            # Allow OO-style access.
);

print $_, "\n" for
    $c->PING_TTL,
    $c->CLIENT_PORT,
    $c->FTP_SERVER,
    $c->FOO,
;
```

Test config file:

```
PING_TTL    | 1               # default ping interval is 1 second
CLIENT_PORT | 7870            # default port
FTP_SERVER  | 192.162.522.222 # ftp server ip address
FOO         | abcd            # Make sure we can handle # and | in comments
```

Output:

```
1
7870
192.162.522.222
abcd
```

Comment: I like the statement "Unless you are doing this as a learning exercise".  Sometimes it is worthwhile trying to do something yourself and realising it is harder (or has pitfalls) and then go to CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

So, what does your program do when `FTP_SERVER` is specified on line 42?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %param;

while ( my $param = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $param =~ /[|]/;
    chomp $param;
    $param =~ s/^\s+//;
    $param =~ s/\s+$//;

    my ($name, $rest) = split /\s* [|] \s*/x, $param;
    my ($value, $comment) = split /\s* [#]  \s*/x, $rest, 2 ;

    $param{$name}{value} = $value;
    $param{$name}{comment} = $comment;
}

use YAML;
print Dump \%param;

__DATA__
PING_TTL   |   1 # default ping interval is 1 second
CLIENT_PORT |   7870 # default port
FTP_SERVER  |   192.162.522.222 # ftp server ip address
```

Output:

```
---
CLIENT_PORT:
  comment: default port
  value: 7870
FTP_SERVER:
  comment: ftp server ip address
  value: 192.162.522.222
PING_TTL:
  comment: default ping interval is 1 second
  value: 1
```

Comment: Good illustration. By the way, the current code doesn't do the right thing if the comment contains `#` or `|`. One fix might be 3-arg `split`, I suppose. Or CPAN?

Comment: @FM CPAN would be the way to go. However, I do not know if there is a module that supports `|` as the delimiter along with inline comments. To the OP: I think you should adopt one of the standard configuration file formats instead of coming up with your own.

Comment: wat are these YAML,  %param , i could not get at all...

i got a config.txt file with a no if values input by user..

$data_file="config.txt";
 open(RAK, $data_file)|| die("Could not open file!");
 @raw_data=<RAK>; 
one os these was 
@Ftp_Server =split(/\|\s/,$raw_data[32]);
my $FTP_SERVER = $Ftp_Server[1];
$raw_data[32] =~ s/ ^ \s+ //x ;
$raw_data[32] =~ s/ \s+ $ //x ;

& i was doing this before each value to be used (like $FTP_SERVER here)

i think your prog does once on all the values thereafter can use any value .

could you please explain w.r.t my program here as i did not get above..

Comment: @rockyurock Are you familiar with loops and data structures in Perl?

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are many good CPAN modules for handling configuration data in files.  One such common module (actually a family of modules) is [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML):

```
use YAML::Tiny;
my $yaml = YAML::Tiny->new;
$yaml = YAML::Tiny->read('myapp_config.yml');
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps split on whitespace generically

```
split(/\s+/, ..);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove space either side of a bar use

```
 split / \s* \| \s* /x , $string
```

This doesnt handle stpace at the start and end of the string. For this do

```
 $string =~ s/ ^ \s+ //x ;
 $string =~ s/ \s+ $ //x ;
```

To remove comments you could do something like

```
 $string =~ s/#[^|]*//g ;
```

This saying remove a `#` and anything following that isnt a `|`.    You could build this into the `split` but this wouldnt handle the last string so I feel it better to treat the # and the split seperately.

Having said this, if you want a robust way, I would look at one of the Config::* modules